# Loop com FOR em Bash quebrando linha no espaço

Tags: bash

Pessoas estou fazendo um loop simples com FOR num script bash para ler cada linha de um arquivo ou variável e imprimir cada uma delas porém quando a frase tem um espaço ele vai para o próximo pulo do FOR.

Código bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
resultados=$(cat file)

for i in $resultados; do
  echo "counter: $i"
done
```

Exemplo de conteúdo do *file*:

```
XXXXX 11:11:11.111 000000 XXXX XXXXXXX XXXXX A B C D E 0 F GH 00<-000000000000000000000000
XXXXX 11:11:11.111 000000 XXXX XXXXXXX XXXXX A B C D E 0 F GH 00<-000000000000000000000000
XXXXX 11:11:11.111 000000 XXXX XXXXXXX XXXXX A B C D E 0 F GH 00<-000000000000000000000000
XXXXX 11:11:11.111 000000 XXXX XXXXXXX XXXXX A B C D E 0 F GH 00<-000000000000000000000000
```

Gostaria que ele imprimisse linha a linha.

Comment: Existe algum empecilho para usar o `while read -r line; do ... done <"arquivo.txt"`?

Comment: acabei utilizando a alternativa do IFS... mas irei testar mais tarde essa possibilidade e retorno com o resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [`IFS` (**I**nternal **F**ield **S**eparator)](https://linux.die.net/abs-guide/internalvariables.html#IFSREF) por padrão usa *whitespace* (espaço, tab, e nova linha), mas você pode ajusta-lo usando para apenas quebra de linha:

```
IFS='
'
```

Ou:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Talvez seja importante posteriormente restaurar o valor do separador, pois você pode precisar usar para outros comandos que usem o separador padrão, então pode fazer algo como:

```
#!/bin/bash

# salva o valor padrão
DEFAULT_IFS=$IFS

# define quebra de linha
IFS=$'\n'

resultados=$(cat foo.txt)

for i in $resultados; do
  echo "$i"
done

# restaura
IFS=$DEFAULT_IFS
```

Ou você pode usar o `read` (use o `-r` para evitar que as barras invertidas escapem de os caracteres), exemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r current; do
echo "$current"
done <foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use o separador IFS pra corrigir isto:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='
'
resultados=$(cat file)

for i in $resultados; do
  echo "counter: $i"
done
```